# Let $A \subset \Bbb R$ be a set of measure $0$. Show that $m(\{e^x:x\in A\})=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Let $A \subset \Bbb R$ be a set of measure $0$. Show that $m(\{e^x:x\in A\})=0$.

Reposting since I was asking for a solution verification, but my attempt was completely wrong.

Since $m(A)=0$ we have that $A \subset \bigcup_{k}I_k$, where $\{I_k\}_k$ is a cover for $A$ and that $m(A) \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell(I_k) < \varepsilon$ for any $\varepsilon >0$.

Now since $f[A]= \{e^x:x\in A\}$, when $f(x) =e^x$ we have that $f[A] \subset f[\bigcup_{k}I_k]= \bigcup_{k} f[I_k]$.

We know that $f$ is continuous so by the mean value theorem $f$ is Lipschitz on $I_k$ (we can assume $I_k$'s are closed since the measure is the same of closed and open sets).

Fix $x_k \in I_k$, now$|f(x)- f(x_k)| \le M|x-x_k| = M\ell(I_k) \implies $  $f(x) \in [f(x_k)- M\ell(I_k), f(x_k)+M\ell(I_k)] \implies f[I_k] \subset [f(x_k)- M\ell(I_k), f(x_k)+M\ell(I_k)] \implies \ell(f([I_k]) \le 2M\ell(I_k).$

Now $m(f[A]) \le \sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell(f[I_k]) =\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2M\ell(I_k) = 2M \sum_{k=1}^\infty \ell(I_k) < 2M \varepsilon \to 0$ thus $m(\{e^x:x\in A\})=0$.

I feel like the reasoning here is correct, but the idea on showing that $\ell(f([I_k]) \le 2M\ell(I_k)$ seemed a bit bruteforce. Is there another way I could have gone about this?

Comment: Continuous functions need not be Lipschitz and your $f$ is not Lipschitz.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is not correct (since $f$ is not Lipschitz on $\mathbb R$) but it can be salvaged. If we show that $m(\{x: -n \leq x \leq n, e^{x}\in A \})=0$ for each $n$ then we can finish the proof by taking union over $n$. But for this your proof works since $f$ is indeed Lipschitz on $[-n,n]$.